# how to add conditional ref to github action step for any release branch

Tags: github, github-actions

The following if statement is not working.

```
    if: github.ref == 'ref/head/release/*' || contains(github.ref, '/tags/release')
```

Everything else runs but the if does not. my branch is called **release/test**
It should run when it sees the branch **release** with anything following that in the. name.

Anyone know why the if statement is not running.

```
name: Publish
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - release/*
env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}-image
  TAG_PREXIX: release-v

jobs:
  Publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: "Bump package version"
        id: bumpVersion
        uses: "phips28/gh-action-bump-version@master"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          PACKAGEJSON_DIR: "./client"
          tag-prefix: ${{env.TAG_PREXIX}}
          major-wording: "MAJOR,BREAKING CHANGE:"
          minor-wording: "feat"
          patch-wording: "patch,fix,bugfix,chore"

      - name: Log into Container registry
        if: github.ref == 'ref/head/release/*' || contains(github.ref, '/tags/release')
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        if: github.ref == 'ref/head/release/*' || contains(github.ref, '/tags/release')
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{env.TAG_PREXIX}}${{steps.bumpVersion.outputs.newTag}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `github.ref == 'ref/head/release/*'`, you ask to Github to match exactly with branch called `release/*'`, no manipulation over `*` is applied.

If you want to match any branch prefixed with `release/`, you need to use the built-in function [startsWith](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#startswith)

```yaml
release:
  if: startsWith(github.ref, 'ref/head/release/') || contains(github.ref, '/tags/release')
  steps: []
```

See you on the workflow :)